# Solving $\frac{x^{3} - 2x^{2} + x + 4}{x+1} = \frac{7}{4}\sin\frac{\pi x}{3}$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

I'd like to simply solve this equation:
$$\frac{x^{3} - 2x^{2} + x + 4}{x+1} = \frac{7}{4}\sin\frac{\pi x}{3}$$
What makes it difficult for me is the conversion between the polynomial expression for $x$ on the left side that should be equal to a trigonometric function of a product of $x$ and a radian value. I've heard of Taylor and Maclaurin's methods, but I don't think it would help. It's probably something quite basic, but it's just new for me. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Use some numerical methods to solve the problem. Btw, $x^3-2x^2+x+4 = (x+1)(x^2-3x+4)$.

Comment: The left side is clear to me, the problem is exactly which of the mentioned `numerical methods` to use to somehow convert that sine of a product to what I need. It's pretty much the first time I've stumbled upon the will to solve a problem if this kind, so I don't really know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: prove that $$x=\frac{3}{2}$$ is the only real solution.
Solve the inequality
$$\left|\frac{x^3-2x^2+x+4}{x+1}\right|\le \frac{7}{4}$$

Comment: That wouldn't be so hard to prove (haven't figured it out yet, but I know how to approach it :D). The question is, how did you know the value to check in the first place. How is that to find and calculate? I'm really interested in the ways to solve that problem.

Comment: I have added the inequality for you!

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help, sir! Only if I hadn't figured it out when I came to check out on your answer! And yet I posted my idea of the solution, which pretty much covers up with your hint. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, what I've come up with was the following idea of working it all out:
As already mentioned,
$$\frac{x^3 - 2x^2 + x + 4}{x+1} = x^2 - 3x + 4$$
which, when factorized right, gives
$$x^2 - 3x + 4 = (x - \frac{3}{2})^2 + \frac{7}{4} \ge \frac{7}{4}$$
whereas the right side
$$\frac{7}{4}sin\frac{\pi x}{3} \le \frac{7}{4}$$

Which inevitably leads to the conclusion that equality is only possible when
$$\begin{array}{|l} (x - \frac{3}{2})^2 + \frac{7}{4} = \frac{7}{4} \\ \frac{7}{4}sin\frac{\pi x}{3} = \frac{7}{4} \end{array}$$
an only solution to which is $x = \frac{3}{2}$. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\;x^3-2x^2+x+4\,$ has the root $\,x=-1\,$ (easy to find by inspection, or the rational root theorem), then the numerator factors as $\,x^3-2x^2+x+4=(x+1)(x^2 - 3 x + 4)\,$, and the fraction on the LHS simplifies to $\,\dfrac{x^3-2x^2+x+4}{x+1}=x^2-3x+4\,$. All that's left is to check the range of the quadratic.